# Terraform import: invalid index

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to replace deprecated resource 'azurerm_sql_server' with the 'azurerm_mssql_server' and got an 'invalid index' error in the case.

A simplified demo of the situation (with Terraform v0.14.5 and v1.0.5):

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.49.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

locals {
  prefix = toset(["primary", "secondary"])
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "rgtest"
  location = "Canada Central"
}

resource "random_password" "sql_admin_password" {
  length      = 16
  special     = true
  number      = true
  upper       = true
  lower       = true
  min_special = 2
  min_numeric = 2
  min_upper   = 2
  min_lower   = 2
}

resource "azurerm_sql_server" "instance" {
  for_each = local.prefix

  name                = "${each.value}-sqlsvr"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "ssadmin"
  administrator_login_password = random_password.sql_admin_password.result
}

locals {
  primary_sql_srv   = azurerm_sql_server.instance["primary"].name
  secondary_sql_srv = azurerm_sql_server.instance["secondary"].name
}

# other TF resources using local.primary_sql_srv and local.secondary_sql_srv
```

The infrastructure has been deployed and no intention to re-create the database servers so we need to change the resource and import existing servers. According to [Terraform document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/2.49.0/docs/guides/migrating-between-renamed-resources), this can be done with 'terraform state rm' and 'terraform import' command.

So,

1. Change the configuration script

```
...

resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "instance" {
...
locals {
  primary_sql_srv   = azurerm_mssql_server.instance["primary"].name
  secondary_sql_srv = azurerm_mssql_server.instance["secondary"].name
}
# other TF resources using local.primary_sql_srv and local.secondary_sql_srv
```

2. Remove azurerm_sql_server resource from the state file, both are successful

```
terraform.exe state rm azurerm_sql_server.instance[`\`"primary`\`"]
terraform.exe state rm azurerm_sql_server.instance[`\`"secondary`\`"]
```

3. Import the primary database server

```
> terraform.exe import azurerm_mssql_server.instance[`\`"primary`\`"] "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rgtest/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/primary-sqlsvr"

azurerm_mssql_server.instance["primary"]: Importing from ID "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rgtest/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/primary-sqlsvr"...
azurerm_mssql_server.instance["primary"]: Import prepared!
  Prepared azurerm_mssql_server for import
azurerm_mssql_server.instance["primary"]: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rgtest/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/primary-sqlsvr]

Import successful!

The resources that were imported are shown above. These resources are now in
your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by Terraform.
```

Current state list

```
❯ terraform.exe state list

azurerm_mssql_server.instance["primary"]
azurerm_resource_group.rg
random_password.sql_admin_password
```

4. Import the secondary database server

```
> terraform.exe import azurerm_mssql_server.instance[`\`"secondary`\`"] "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rgtest/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/secondary-sqlsvr"

azurerm_mssql_server.instance["secondary"]: Importing from ID "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rgtest/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/secondary-sqlsvr"...
azurerm_mssql_server.instance["secondary"]: Import prepared!
  Prepared azurerm_mssql_server for import
azurerm_mssql_server.instance["secondary"]: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rgtest/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/secondary-sqlsvr]

Error: Invalid index

  on C:\Work\Projects\2021\20210812RenameResource\t1env\main.tf line 49, in locals:
  49:   secondary_sql_srv = azurerm_mssql_server.instance["secondary"].name
    |----------------
    | azurerm_mssql_server.instance is object with 1 attribute "primary"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

The state refresh for the 2nd import hit the locals block and failed due to no 'secondary' server resource.

So to me, this is a deadlock, I cannot import the 'secondary' server resource because of the refresh error and the refresh error was caused by the lack of the 'secondary' server resource.

Two ways I can think of:

1. Manually add the 'secondary' server resource to the state file, which is definitely not proper
2. Remove the 'locals' block which is OK in the demo but lots of changes in real code for dependencies.

Any thoughts, please? Thank you.

Comment: This is a bug in `terraform import` that was introduced in version 0.13 and I would have hoped would be fixed by now. It erroneously attempts to validate `locals` in the config against non-existent state during an `import` instead of ignoring it as impossible. What version of Terraform is this?

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks. I just added the version to the question, v0.14.5. I'll try the latest version on the demo.

Comment: If it is still not fixed in the latest version, then I can discuss workarounds.

Comment: Hi Matt, just tested with v1.0.5, same error. What are the workarounds? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in `terraform import` that was introduced in version 0.13. During a `terraform import` execution, it will attempt to validate the `local` variables in the config containing the resource namespace against non-existent state. There are basically three workarounds for this:

1. Downgrade temporarily to Terraform 0.12 where this bug does not exist.

This is really not a great option because the version(s) is stored in the state, and you may be locked out of executing terraform CLI commands against the state synced with a later version.

2. Manually modify the state to contain the resources.

Also really not a great option because this could corrupt the state and/or cause other obvious issues with malformation.

3. Temporarily comment out the relevant `locals` and any code referencing the `local` variable values.

This is what I always ended up using. You can do a multiline comment in the `/* ... */` style around the relevant `locals` that references the exported resource attributes of the imported resource, and you will also need to do so in any other areas of the config that reference the `local` variables. You can then uncomment the code once the imports are complete.

Comment: Do you perhaps have link to the bug issue on GH if there is one?

Comment: @Marcin I never filed one for this, and did not check for one. I believe I just had just come off filing two others recently and felt burned out on them at the time.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Yes, making GH issues is full-time job sometimes:-)

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks for the workarounds, I'll try the 3rd one. The tricky thing is these codes are in a shared module that is being used by 100+ app environments so complicated situation.

Comment: @JWU I should mention that the document you linked to that recommends a `state rm` followed by an `import` is only accurate if the API resource ID format has also changed. If that is not true and only the provider resource name has changed, then you can actually do a `state mv` instead, and that would avoid all of this mess. Maybe give that a try real quick to see how it goes.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Terraform document says "if you are moving a resource or a resource instance then you can only move it to a new address with the same resource type." In this case, the type is changed. Verified in a quick test,  got 'resource types don't match' error.

Comment: @JWU Ok so the provider resource changed to match a change in the API; so yes sorry you are out of luck on that path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with terraform 1.2.8, updated to 1.3.0 and the import was successfull. Looks like this last version resolves the issue ?

**edit** : As stated in [Terraform v1.3 changelog](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/v1.3/CHANGELOG.md) :

> `terraform import`: Better handling of resources or modules that use `for_each`, and situations where data resources are needed to complete the operation. ([#31283](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/31283))

This description matches my situation 100% (use of for_each, data blocs & modules).

Comment: Great. Edit your answer. Don't "hide" useful information in the comment section.